# break from for loop in python

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, break

I'm using a `break` command in my for loop but it doesn't seem to be working.
Here's my code:

```
    winw = 60
    winh = 40
    for i in range(num_scale_steps):
        print "in iteration %d " % i
        # some code that will crash if winw > 240
        winw = 10 + winw
        winh = 10 + winh
        print "new width:%d"   % winw
        if (winh > 360) or(winw > 240) :
            break
```

But it doesn't break. The last outputs it gives are:

```
new width 240
in iteration 18
new width:250 --> at this point it should break and not continue to next iteration
in iteration 19  
# then it crashes because winw > 240
```

250 is greater than 240. But why does the loop not break before getting to iteration 19?

Comment: It *does* break right after winw = 250 (that's the last print and then it breaks). Check again.

Comment: If you are expecting it to break in the previous iteration, you need to use `>=` not `>`

Comment: Do you mean your loop continues after iteration 19? Or is iteration 19 the last and you wonder how you ever got higher than 240?

Comment: it shouldn't  get to the line `print "in iteration %d" %i`. It should break before that. I haven't put all my code, only the relevant code, but actually it breaks because of an error at the beginning of the loop, which it should have actually broken out of before.

Comment: @HansThen Just edited my question. It shouldn't even get to iteration 19, because in 18 it's already bigger than 240.

Comment: Try running just the code you provided.  No iteration 19.

Comment: Yes, the code does not behave as you describe.

Comment: Can the people who want to close this question please try the code again? My question is valid. This code doesn't work as expected.

Comment: I have tried your code. I see no iteration 19. However, your window size does exceed the maximum width of 240 after the last iteration. If that is a problem, then it will surely crash.

Comment: Can't reproduce your results, please check your code again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should take care your `winh` or `winw` never exceed your intended maximum. To ensure this you need to test that the value plus the stepsize does not exceed the maximum before you actually change the window size.

The solution provided by others (using `>=` or changing the execution order) will only solve your problem as long as you start with multiples of ten. Try the following. I have taken the liberty of tweaking your code a bit.

```
winw = 60
winh = 40
stepsize = 10
for i in range(num_scale_steps):
    if (winh + stepsize > 360) or(winw + stepsize > 240) :
        break
    print "in iteration %d " % i
    winw += stepsize
    winh += stepsize
    print "new width:%d"   % winw
```

Comment: Thanks, this works. But I don't understand what exactly was wrong with my code?

Comment: You tested if the value was outside the allowed range _after_ you changed the variables `winw` and `winh`. So one of their values would always end up (just) outside of the allowed range.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
  winw = 60
    winh = 40
    for i in range(num_scale_steps):
        if (winh > 360) or(winw > 240) :
            break
        print "in iteration %d " % i
        winw = 10 + winw
        winh = 10 + winh
        print "new width:%d"   % winw
```

You need to check the condition before you are printing the new values.

Comment: I tried this. No difference.